# cannot define List of 'a->'b functions

Tags: generics, module, f#

I have 2 modules: stopwatch and clock, stopwatch emits a start and stop action and clock does not emit any action.

stopwatch handles start,stop and update actions

click handles only update action but the update action is not the same as the stopwatch.

stopwatch action types

```
type ActionType =
  | Start          of StartActionData
  | Stop           of int
  | Update         of int
```

clock action types

```
type ActionType =
  | Update         of (int * TimeZone)
```

My application consumes both stopwatch and clock so the application action tpe is:

```
type Action =
  | StopWatch of StopWatchAction
  | Clock of ClockAction
```

When a module (stopwatch or clock) creates an action it will wrap that action into a wrapper function that will return a union type that application can use.

For example stopwatch creates a stop action:

```
(wrapper:(StopWatchAction -> 'a)) {
  ``type`` = (Stop startTime)
  index = index
}
```

The to `'a` is because the modules are unaware of the application that will consume them but `'a` is Application.Action union type.

When an action arrives at the application handler it will use that union type to delegate the action to the module handler:

```
match action with
  | ApplicationTypes.StopWatch action ->
    {state with//return application state
      //set the stopwatch state with updated state
      //  provided by the mediator in stop watch
      StopWatch = 
        StopWatchMediator.handleAction
          state.StopWatch
          action
    }
```

The problem is that I have a timer module that takes wrappers like `(StopWatch.Action->Application.Action)` and `(Clock.Action->Application.Action)`

It will emit an update action every second, the update action also needs a createAction function of both stopwatch and clock but that is for later concern.

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to create a list of `('a->'b)` functions, the code in timer is:

```
let mutable wrappers:(('a -> 'b) list) = []
let addWrapper wrapper =
  wrappers <- wrapper::wrappers
```

In my main application file I try calling it like so:

```
addWrapper ApplicationTypes.StopWatch
addWrapper ApplicationTypes.Clock
```

The timer module should be able to dispatch actions of any kind using a wrapper of `('a->'b)` periodically.

Both the wrapper and action creator are injected by the application since the application knows what modules need a timer, how to wrap the action and what function to use to create the action).

Answer (score 4):

You're hitting the F# "value restriction" error. If you aren't familiar with it, you should read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/ before proceeding to the rest of this answer. I'll try to explain.

In F#, functions can be generic, but values must be *specific*. A list can't actually hold two different values; that is, you can't have a list of `'a -> 'b` functions where `'a` means something different for different items of the list. You can only have a list of `int -> string` functions, or a list of `Clock -> ClockResult` functions, and so on. If you want a list of functions where some have type `StopWatch.Action -> Application.Action` and others have type `Clock.Action -> Application.Action`, then you need to combine those somehow so that they'll be the same type before you can store them in the list. E.g.,

```
type ActionWrapper =
    | StopWatch of StopWatch.Action -> Application.Action
    | Clock of Clock.Action -> Application.Action

let mutable wrappers : ActionWrapper list = []
let addWrapper (wrapper : ActionWrapper) =
    wrappers <- wrapper :: wrappers

let addStopWatchWrapper (wrapper : StopWatch.Action -> Application.Action) =
    addWrapper (StopWatch wrapper)
let addClockWrapper (wrapper : Clock.Action -> Application.Action) =
    addWrapper (Clock wrapper)
```

Now your `wrappers` list is all of the same type, and you'll be able to use the `addStopWatchWrapper` or `addClockWrapper` function as appropriate.

P.S. Why are you using a `mutable` wrapper list that functions as a global? To me, that's a bit of a code smell: you're going to get "spooky action at a distance", and all the rest of the problems associated with mutating global state. You'll have dependencies between different parts of your code depending on which one runs first (and mutates the global state) and which one runs second (and sees a mutated global state), but those dependencies will be **hidden**: you won't know they're there just by reading the code. It's much better to pass that state around as a function parameter; that way your code dependencies are explicit and you're in for fewer surprises later on. (And in programming, "surprises" = "bugs"). But fixing your design to not have mutable state is a much larger topic, so I'll limit myself in this answer to explaining what's going on with your `wrappers` list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was using mutable trying to port this from JavaScript in a Fable project. Using ActionWrapper will work but timer is no longer a module, Either ActionWrapper is defined in timer thus timer knows about the other modules that will consume it or it is defined in application thus the timer has upward dependency (timer has a dependency to it's consumer). I will play with this as ActionWrapper may be inserted as a dependency by the application, then when creating timer the wrappers do not need to be mutable as well.

Comment: The whole point of timer is to cause side effects (it will emit actions periodically). The timer module it self has no state. Project is here: https://github.com/amsterdamharu/programmingbook/tree/example9